# extract particular pattern from a file in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I try to extract a particular pattern from a file. the file content:

```
--------some other command in here----------
<tr>
<td>someWords</td>
<td>anotherWords</td>
</tr>
--------some other command in here-----------
the <tr>...</tr> patter occur again
```

I try to extract the tr pattern from the file

in the shell script I write:

read INPUT

```
grep '<tr>\n<td>[A-Za-z0-9,<,>,/]</td>\n<td>[A-Za-z0-9,<,>,/]</td>\n</tr>
```

However, this command doesnt work. Any idea? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/p' file
```

see example:

```
kent$  cat a                      
--------some other command in here----------
<tr>
<td>someWords</td>
<td>anotherWords</td>
</tr>
--------some other command in here-----------
the 
<tr>
<td>someOtherWords</td>
<td>anotherWords2</td>
</tr>

kent$  sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/p' a
<tr>
<td>someWords</td>
<td>anotherWords</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>someOtherWords</td>
<td>anotherWords2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it didnot work. I tried it in my shell. since I am using standard input, I only write sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/p' However, nothing change at all.

Comment: @user1988385 did you do like  `my standard input command|sed ...` it should work.

Comment: something wrong w/ my shell T.T I try it in the terminal (using sed -n '/<tr>/,/<\/tr>/p' a command) it work perfectly. However, for some reason, I cant do it in shell